# QT KernelBase!RaiseException at 0x759fc41f

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

A comment more than a question:
The following describes an issue I had this evening and what I did to "correct" it.  These events required a few hours of time to resolve. As this site is one of my favorite sources of information, thought this post might benefit someone else. Any constructive comments on diagnosing QT Creator run-time exceptions would be welcome. The exception seems to have been the result of corruption in the symbol file for QCored.

Exception (QtCreator debugger KernelBase Exception)

```
Exception at 0x759fc41f, code: 0x406d1388: Startup complete, flags-0x0 (first chance) in KernelBase!RaiseException
```

---

Windows: QtCreator 3.0:

Configuration Build:    build-QMRC-Qt_5_2_0_msvc2010_opengl-Debug

Application Output Window displayed exception with a valid  build.

Corrective Action:

Deleted Windows subdirectories:

c:\users\\appdata\local\temp\

Run qmake 
rebuild debug mode